# space issue using sed command

Tags: shell, unix, sed, sh

var=abc cde fgh ijk

I have ran below command

```
 sed -i '$s/}/,\n"filename":"'$var'/g"}/'
```

getting below error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unterminated `s' command
```

because "abc cde fgh ijk" having spaces inbetween the string value.

Expected output is to print : abc cde fgh ijk

Thanks

Comment: There's no `}` in your input so what are you hoping `s/}/...` will do? [edit] your question to provide clearer and more truly representative sample input and expected output as it feels like your real data doesn't actually look like the sample you've shown us.

Comment: If you are trying to modify a JSON value, put `sed` away and use a tool like `jq`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$var` to `"$var"`.  Otherwise the space in `var` is visible to bash as an arg separator, terminating the sed "program".

Comment: if i used "" means its taking as a string and print as it is like $var but i want to print abc cde fgh ijk

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$cat f
Hello vipin
$var="abc cde fgh ijk"
$sed "s/Hello/$var/g" f
abc cde fgh ijk vipin
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.
i tried to get var value to the variable name filename. so i tried with below command.
$sed -i '$s/}/,\n"filename":"'$var/g'"}/' file.json
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
getting the same error

Comment: i want to read var ( abc cde fgh ijk )with space only but if i use /g i am getting the same error

Comment: Try this - `sed -i "s/}/,\nfilename:$var/g" file.txt`

Comment: vipin, actually its like a loop process so i need to use }/. if i use its showing the same error.

Comment: If you can share input file and expected output, that would be easier to solve this query.

Comment: @Manimekalai - Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. First, yes, the spaces are confusing `sed` since you are passing them unquoted. Then, you also have a syntax error in `g}/`. The syntax of the substitution operator is:

```
s/original/replacement/options
```

For example:

```
s/foo/bar/g
```

But you are using:

```
s/foo/bar/g"}/
```

In any case, unless you have multiple `}` on the last line of your file, the `g` is pointless.

So, depending on what you are actually trying to do, you want one of (UI have removed the `-i` to show the output, add it again to make the replacement modify the original file):

```
$ cat file 
foo
bar}
$ sed  '$s/}/,\n"filename":"'"$var\"\}/" file 
foo
bar,
"filename":"abc cde fgh ijk"}
```

Or

```
$ cat file
foo
bar}}}
$ sed  '$s/}/,\n"filename":"'"$var\"\}/g" file 
foo
bar,
"filename":"abc cde fgh ijk"},
"filename":"abc cde fgh ijk"},
"filename":"abc cde fgh ijk"}
```

Of course, a much simpler approach would be to have set `var` to hold the entire target replacement, quotes and all:

```
$ cat file
foo
bar}
$ var=',\n"filename":"abc cde fgh ijk"}'
$ sed "\$s/}/$var/" file 
foo
bar,
"filename":"abc cde fgh ijk"}
```

Note that now that we're using double quotes, the `$` in the `sed` expression needs to be escaped.

Comment: thanks for your clear explanation, here 
in the json file i am having the below details

var =abc cde fgh ijk
example.json
{
    "ETag": "\"c489228521fa35447XXXXXXXX\"",
    "Metadata": {}
}

query: sed -i '$s/}/,\n"filename":"'$var'"}/' example.json

expected output:
{
    "ETag": "\"c489228521fa35447XXXXXXXX\"",
    "Metadata": {},
 "filename":"abc cde fgh ijk"
}

but error showing like
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated `s' comman